# Get data from POST ajax call using web2py

Tags: python, ajax, web2py

I'm making an AJAX call to a python function. That function does a database query based on the information sent to the function.

I can't work out how to get the variable that is sent to the function.

I was using request.vars.variableName, and I know the function is valid, it's just not receiving the variable to use properly. How do I get POST sent variables from a python function, using web2py?

ETA: This is the code I was using

```
jQuery.ajax(
        {type: "POST",
        url: '../../Printed/printedballoons/cost.json', //python function
        data: typeSelected,//data sent to server
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(msg){$("#ajaxerror").html(msg);},
        success: function(data){
            balloonPrice = data.cost;
        },
        timeout: 2000}
    );
```

The error was in the "data: typeSelected" line, the variable name wasnt associated with any data, so the python query:

```
cost=db(db.balloonprices.type==request.vars.typeSelected).select(db.balloonprices.cost)
```

was looking for "" as opposed to a anything that actually is in the database.

Comment: The solution is to have "data: {dataSelected: value},"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.post_vars
```

They are copied to `request.vars` also if there is no request.get_vars

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

AJAX call:

```
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/app/func",
          data: "array="+JSON.stringify(tempArray)
       }).done(function( msg ) { });
```

controller:

```
def func():    
   temparray = json.loads(request.post_vars.array)
```

Hope it'll help you