# How to pass a jquery variable to a Python script?

Tags: jquery, python, mongodb, variables, pymongo

I have an html form, with a jquery script to make it dynamic.

I use Apache2 under debian wheezy for the server,

MongoDB for database,

Pymongo as driver,

At the end, when the form is completed, all the fields are stored in a variable in my .js file, with a json format as follow :

```
var payload = {"field1":"Richard","field2":"Berroy"}
```

When you click on the submit button, I use an ajax post function :

```
$("#submitbtn").click( function() {
var payload = {"field1":"Richard","field2":"Berroy"}
$.post('python/mongo_brief_write.py', {bn: payload});
```

The goal of mongo_brief_write.py is to insert the content of the payload var into a collection of my MongoDB database, using pymongo driver.

here is my code for this python script :

```
import pymongo
import json
import requests
from pymongo import Connection
//test = {"field1":"Richard","field2":"Berroy"}
chain = request.POST[bn]
con = Connection("mongodb://192.xxx.xx.xxx/")
db = con.central
collection = db.brief
post_id = collection.insert(chain)
```

If I choose my test var it works fine, but I always have an issue if I comment test and use that request line, I don't now how to get that json object from my jquery form, to store it in the database ?

Thank you

Comment: What's the error information did you get? And by the way, you should use `#` to comment python code.

Comment: Hi Leon, you're right for the #
I Have
 
`POST http://192.168.15.200/central/python/mongo_brief_write.py 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
send jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.3.js:7986
(anonymous function) central.js:910
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.3.js:3058
elemData.handle.eventHandle`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `get` like

```
chain = request.POST.get('bn')
```

to check your `post variable` test it by using

```
request.post_vars
```

Url's may help you [Passing list of values to django view via jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176594/passing-list-of-values-to-django-view-via-jquery-ajax-call) and [Get data from POST ajax call using web2py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781187/get-data-from-post-ajax-call-using-web2py)

Comment: Thank you Rohan, I don't understand why I need to use wep2py, Django or pybottle to perform a simple action. I mean on the other way it is that simple, I have a python script with pymongo that read my database and pass the content as a json object in my jquery environnement for display purpose without a third party program. Now I just want to write in my mongodb the content of the form and it is different ?

Comment: I've tried your request above and I have the same error, should I import something in my python script ?