# Python Flask get a value from a html page

Tags: python, html, flask

Hallo I want to use a Number from html in python flask

```
<a id="clicks1"  name='nm'>20</a>
```

I want to use it in python like

```
liter = request.form.get("nm")
```

Comment: That's not a form input element.

Comment: Go to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp and learn about inputs. Then try to use it with your case.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through all these links: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Moreover, `a` tag is not an input element. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847287) helpful?

Comment: and is there a way to get the innerHtml from a <a> tag with python falsk